# Getting the total count of array list elements from all documents of a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNPNn.png)I am trying to get the activity of my users in which I am trying to get the total followers and following of all users in my userinfo table.

I am using the below command line query to get that which is working fine and I am getting the total count.

```
db.userinfo.aggregate([
{ "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "followersCount": {
        "$sum": {
            "$size": { $ifNull: [ "$followers", [] ] }
        }
    },
    "followingCount": {
        "$sum": {
            "$size": { $ifNull: [ "$i_am_following", [] ] }
        }
    }
}}
])
```

But I am unable to replicate this using java programming. Can we write this query in java using BasicDBObjects or Is there any other way to do this?

Here is the sample data for a single user.

```
db.userinfo.insert (
{  
"username" : "user1",
"useremail" : "user1@gmail.com", 
"password" : "password",
"firstname" : "firstname", 
"lastname" : "lastname", 
"dob" : "24-05-1992",
"followers" : [
    {
        "user" : "user2", 
        "from_date" : "2016-12-15 09:59:04"
    },
    {
        "user" : "user3", 
        "from_date" : "2016-12-15 08:59:04"
    }
], 
"i_am_following" : [
    {
        "user" : "user2", 
        "from_date" : "2016-12-15 08:59:04"
    },
    {
        "user" : "user3", 
        "from_date" : "2016-12-15 09:59:04"
    }
]
})
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: BasicDBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id",null);
   groupFields.put("heartCount",new BasicDBObject("$sum",
       new BasicDBObject("$size", new BasicDBObject("$ifNull",Arrays.asList("$hearts",new ArrayList<>())))));
   BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",groupFields);  I tried lot of different ways but ended up with this which infact is not working.

Comment: Consider adding some sample doc.

Comment: @Shravya Verified with your data. You should be good to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

Bson group = group(null,
    sum("followersCount", computed("$size",
        computed("$ifNull",
            asList("$followers", EMPTY_LIST)))),
    sum("followingCount", computed("$size",
        computed("$ifNull",
            asList("$i_am_following", EMPTY_LIST))))
);

AggregateIterable <Document> output = userinfo.aggregate(asList(group));
```

Comment: I am getting com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 168: 'Unrecognized expression '$followers'' when I try the above code.

Comment: I'm on 3.4.1 version. I get this response `{_id=null, followersCount=2, followingCount=2}` with the sample doc.

Comment: I was using 3.4.0 before and Now I changed the version to 3.4.1 and still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I can clearly see that you got the right output and I think I am missing something to make this work. I will be attaching a screen shot of my error in my question.

Comment: You are not using the updated code from the answer. I've updated the code to get rid of `new Document` part yesterday.